How can I setup Google Analytics for my React App?
I'm currently integrating Firebase with my Web React App.
To integrate Google Analytics I was using the Google Tag Manager script on the page header tag, and without any extra configuration, I was able to view all the tracking about my website usage (Pages visited, user traffic, user demographics etc...)
Now, I want to migrate from GTM to Firebase Analitycs, and I'm looking for a way to achieve the same result (being able to track the website usage with no extra configuration) using the "firebase/analytics" package. Is this possible?
I already tried using:
  const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const analytics = getAnalytics(firebaseApp);

and even if it works to trigger events, it doesn't track the information regarding Views by Page title and screen name since that call is tied to a specific component and not the whole app.

Wouldn't be a more appropriate title "... setup Firebase Analitycs ..." then, instead of "... setup Google Analytics ..." ? Or "... migrate Google Analytics to Firebase Analitycs ..." ?
